# Ceiling fan with light and remote issues

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling-fan, remote-control

We purchased and installed new ceiling fan/light with remote about three months ago. We have not had any problems with it since we installed it but the last 24 hours I have been quarantined to my room while waiting Covid test results. At least 3 times the light has shut off on its own. The last time about five minutes after I turned it back on the ceiling fan started on its own. Any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate brand/model of the fan. Is it a RF (radio frequency) or IR (infrared light) remote? If it's RF, there may be another device somewhere in your neighborhood that someone just brought home that's transmitting the appropriate signals that are propagating through your walls. If it's IR, it could be that your TV remote could match up with the light pattern that the fan receiver understands.

Comment: What make and model is your fan? What are you using in it for lightbulbs, or does it have an integrated (usually LED) light that's hardwired into the unit?